# What could be the alternative of not serializing a value-based class such as LocalDateTime

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Lets assume we have an entity which implements Serializable. In the entity class we have a LocalDateTime field. According to this [Value-based classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) rule, it might produce unpredictable results in case of deserialization.

So lets say we want to store them in http session then, my question is what could be the alternative in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the page you are linking to says is

> A program may produce unpredictable results if it attempts to
>   distinguish two references to equal values of a value-based class…

So generally there are no issues with serializing and deserializing objects of such classes. If you serialize, say, a `LocalDateTime` and deserialize it again, you will get an object that is equal to the first one. That’s generally all you need.

If you serialize two objects with references to *the same* `LocalDateTime`, you may get two objects with references to two equal, but distinct `LocalDateTime`. Or the other way around, if you serialize two objects with references to two different but equal `LocalDateTime`, they could theoretically come back with references to one and the same object.

What this means, is that after deserialization, unexpected results may come from, for example

```
if (myLocalDateTime == myOtherLocalDateTime)
```

You ask

> what could be the alternative in this case?

The alternative is: always compare such objects with `.equals`:

```
if (myLocalDateTime.equals(myOtherLocalDateTime))
```

Then you’re safe.